# Putting $X$ in a $2\times4$ table so that there are no nearby $X$

Tags: combinatorics

There is a $2\times4$ table :

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & & &\\ \hline
 &  & &\\ \hline
\end{array}
In how many ways can I put ant amount of $X$ in the chart ,so that there are no nearby $X$?

nearby situations are:
 \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &X & &\\ \hline
 & X & &\\ \hline
\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &X &X &\\ \hline
 &  & &\\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.  Find a recursion for $a_n$, the number of ways of putting $X$s not nearby in a $2\times n$ table.

Note that $a_n$ is also the number of length-$n$ strings of 3 digits $\{0,1,2\}$ with no two adjacent $1$ and no two adjacent $2$.

Comment: thanks :) is there a way without  recursion?

Comment: Maybe. Recursion is the approach that I recommend. Again, what have you tried?